# Django 'global name' error

Tags: python, django

I am setting up my first Django app. I am having some trouble getting my database model to work.

Here is my template:

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load humanize %}
{% block title %}I am a Django God - {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Delusions of Grandeur #{{ munber }}</h1>
  <p>They make life EXCITING for {{ thing }}.</p>
  <p>{% if munber %}Number exists!{% else %}booooo{% endif %}</p>
  <p>
    There are {{ munber }} dog{{ munber|pluralize }} and {{ single|apnumber }}
    ocelot{{ single|pluralize }}.
  </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Here is views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    munber = 6
    thing = "Thinnged Nam"
    things = Thing.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'munber': munber,
        'single': 1,
        'thing': thing,
        'things':things,
    })
```

My error is

> Request Method: GET
>   Request URL: http://localhost:8000/
>
> Django Version: 1.9.2
>   Python Version: 2.7.11
>   Installed Applications:
>   ['collection',
>    'django.contrib.admin',
>    'django.contrib.auth',
>    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>    'django.contrib.sessions',
>    'django.contrib.messages',
>    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>    'django.contrib.humanize']
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
>    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
>    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/wogsland/Projects/hellowebapp/collection/views.py" in index
>     7.     things = Thing.objects.all()
>
> Exception Type: NameError at /
>   Exception Value: global name 'Thing' is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't imported your `Thing` class into your `views.py` file. Assuming your `models.py` is in the same folder as `views.py`, you could update your `views.py` to:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Thing

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    munber = 6
    thing = "Thinnged Nam"
    things = Thing.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'munber': munber,
        'single': 1,
        'thing': thing,
        'things':things,
    })
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks!